# Converting list with elements of different sizes into data frame in R

Tags: r

I have been struggling with this error for a while now, so I was wondering if anyone knows how I can do this?

I've got a list in R containing ~10 sublists (I apologise if I am using the wrong terminology). Overall, my object looks like:

```
head(list)

[[1]]
[[1]]$`LISTNAME1`
[1] "item1"     "item2"       "item3"       "item4"   

[[2]]
[[2]]$`LISTNAME2`
[1] "item2"   "item3"     "item2109"   

[...]
    
[[10]]
[[10]]$`LISTNAME10`
[1] "item3"   "item213199"     "item291212"
```

In other words, each sublist within the list contains different lengths, and may or may not contain different elements. What I want to do is convert this to a data frame, where one column contains the name of the list in the previous object, and the second column contains the elements separated by a single space. Example:

```
LISTNAME1        item1 item2 item3 item4
LISTNAME2        item2 item3 item2109 
...
LISTNAME10       item3 item213199 item291212
```

This was working previously using something like:

```
everything_df <- plyr::ldply(everything, rbind)
```

Plus some aftercode to remove NA values. But for some reason now I am getting this error:

```
Error in output[rng, lcols[[i]]] <- matrices[[i]] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Any ideas on how can I fix this, or if there are better ways of doing this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you just want to `paste` together the "item##" values?

Comment: Do you multiple columns or a single column

Comment: Yes, the items of each "sublist" will be pasted together into a single cell in the final output dataframe.

Comment: `stack(rapply(lst1, paste, collapse = " "))` or `stack(rapply(lst1, toString))` if you want them to be comma separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` with `enframe` to return a tibble with the first column the `name` of the `list` element and the second column a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfr(lst1, enframe)
```

If we need to `paste` the `list` elements together

```
map_dfr(lst1, ~ enframe(.x) %>%
                  mutate(value = map_chr(value, str_c, collapse=", ")))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  name      value                     
#   <chr>     <chr>                     
#1 LISTNAME1 item1, item2, item3, item4
#2 LISTNAME2 item2, item3, item32109
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(list(LISTNAME1 = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4")), 
     list(LISTNAME2 = c("item2", "item3", "item32109")))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks a lot for this! The first part of the code works very well for my data! `map_dfr(lst1, enframe)`, but the second bit which is formatting my results to not show strings looking like vectors (e.g. `c("item1", "item2", "item3")`) is not working. It's showing: `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'str_c' not found`. I'm still looking into it! But thanks a lot, this helps!!

Comment: @RodrigoDuarte forgot to add the `library(stringr)` now, it should work for you

Comment: Ohhh, that was it! Thank you, it worked! 

It was possible to fix it too using @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1's suggestion: `stack(rapply(lst1, paste, collapse = " "))`

Comment: You also may use `library(tidyverse)`. It loads purrr, magritirr, dplyr, string, ggplot, ....

Answer (score 1):

You can `unlist` one level and combine the data into one comma-separated string.

```
result <- stack(sapply(unlist(lst1, recursive = FALSE), toString))[2:1]
```